# Routing Error due to nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting the below error when running a Rail App. I believe it is being caused because Rails is showing comments from 0, instead of 1. The record 0 does not exist. All I want to do is make it possible to edit each comment.

I think the error is how I am creating the links to nested resources (ie linking to comments from posts).

**Error**

> "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments", :post_id=>1, **:id=>nil}**
>   Try running rake routes for more information on available routes."

**show.html.erb:**

```
<% @post.comments.each do |c| %>
<p>
  <b><%=h c.name %> said:</b><br />
  <%= c.created_at %>
</p>

<p>
  <%=h c.body %>
</p>

<p>
  <%=h c.id %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'test', post_comment_path(:post_id => @post.id, :id => c.id) %> |

<%#= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_comment_path(:id => @comment.id,
                                           :id => @post.id) %>

<%= link_to 'Comment', [@post, :comments ] %> |
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path(@comment) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', comments_path %>
```

When I remove this line, the error goes away.

> <%= link_to 'test', post_comment_path(:post_id => @post.id, :id => c.id) %> |

rakes routes output:

```
   C:\RUBY\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\ruby.exe -e  $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)
    C:\RUBY\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\rake routes
          posts_list GET    /posts/list(.:format)                       posts#list
       post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                     POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
    new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
   edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
        post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                     PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)             comments#destroy
               posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                     POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
            new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
           edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
                post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                     PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                     DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy

   Process finished with exit code 0
```

**UPDATE:**

The following now works. I needed to pass the id values within the link.

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_comment_path(@post.id, c) %>

<%= link_to 'Destroy', [c.post, c], :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: Please add you `$ rake routes` output.

Comment: "I believe it is being caused because Rails is showing comments from 0, instead of 1"

This is wrong assumption. `@post.comments` returns a collection of comment objects so when you iterate through that collection using `each` you get a comment object in each cycle. It has nothing to do with item position in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for link generation

```
<%= link_to 'test', post_comment_path(@post, c) %>
```

or even

```
<%= link_to 'test', [@post, c] %>
```

Comment: This appears to work. "c" brings back the comments id number.